# Develop VBA app on Excel version 365 for older versions i.e. Excel 2012

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to develop an Excel-VBA application for i.e. version 2012, but using version 365?

Reason for this question is that I sometimes develop clean VBA applications for clients in 365, but when executing in their environment the code breaks for countless errors, mostly not finding certain command names. Currently, I find myself developing the VBA applications for older versions on the clients' computers as a workaround.

Comment: If you're asking - can Office 365 behave or impersonate earlier versions of Office, I think the answer is just: No.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400133/office-365-versus-desktop-excel-macros